# Import solves error Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'xx' before initialization

Tags: angular, typescript

im working on a strange error right now.
I have this service file, where all other services are stored.
Beside importing all services, which are used in the frontend, I store one component in the import section.

```
import { VacationComponent } from 'app/view/vacation/vacation.component';
```

The import is grey, so it is not in use.
I removed it and ran into the following error:

```
main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'nX' before initialization
at main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:1825981
at Module.zUnb (main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:1826937)
at l (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:552)
at 0 (main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:5659)
at l (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:552)
at t (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:421)
at Array.r [as push] (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:293)
at main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:47
```

When adding the import into the main service file the error disappears.
I don't understand how an unused import can fix this error. Also the imported component has no variable "nX" in it.
The referenced main file from the error contains a definition of nX which looks like the following

```
let nX=(()=>{class t{constructor(t,e){this.service=t,this.dialog=e,this.isChecked=!1}
```

I can see no connection to the imported component.

Comment: Imported component having dependency on the injected service/library ?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you declare the service after the component, then it cannot access the service

Comment: is VacationComponent is having  dependency on the injected service/library

Answer (score 0):

`nx` is just bundling and minification and all that stuff. It turns all your `reallyLongHelpfulNamesForThings` into `a` to keep sizes down.

As the comments, suggest, there are questions to be answered.

How are the component and service related - what's their usage of each other? Is the component being declared properly in the module?

Give us some surrounding context for these items.